# Gnus: How to strip all html tags from incoming mails

Tags: gnus

I want gnus to remove all html tags from incoming mails, displaying only the text. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this function

```el
(defun strip-html ()
  "Remove HTML tags from the current buffer, 
   (this will affect the whole buffer regardless of the restrictions in effect)."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "<[^<]*>" (point-max) t)
    (replace-match "\\1"))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "&copy;" "(c)")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "&amp;" "&")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "&lt;" "<")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "&gt;" ">")
      (goto-char (point-min)))))
```

source: http://sachachua.com/notebook/emacs/small-functions.el